# calc 3 change of variable question

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Inside integrals for change of variables, some problems use  v times the Jacobian, but other problems use the equation of the function times the Jacobian. When do I use just v and when do I use the equation? 
[image]
[image: image2]

The first one demonstrates v*Jacobian and the second picture demonstrates the equation*Jacobian.

Comment: Can you give examples of the different types of integral problems?

Comment: What's v? One of the variables? Some examples would help.

Comment: for change of variables you change x y and z to u v and w.  So the formula to find the integrals over region R is integral sign integral sign v*J(u,v) du dv  But, sometimes instead of v*J(u,v) the formula given for the function is used.  Sorry if this is confusing. I will try to add an example. I'm new to this and it won't let me add a picture

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/WCGcoim
here is a link to pictures of two examples - sorry if they are confusing

Comment: That one turned out that way because v and the integrand 5x+y were the same.

Answer (score 1):

In general you integrate $f$, the given integrand, times the Jacobian, but first you need to replace things to be in terms of the new variables $u$ and $v$. Sometimes this is most easily done by solving for $x$ and $y$ and simply plugging in $f(x(u,v),y(u,v))$. Other times we can take a shortcut if we can figure out how to write the integrand as a function of $u$ and $v$ more directly. In this latter case we can also take a shortcut in finding the Jacobian, by finding the Jacobian of the $(x,y) \mapsto (u,v)$ transformation and taking its reciprocal.